# What is a good (cheap) way to slow down a fan with a thermistor?

Tags: fan, thermistor

What is a good (cheap) practice to manage a fan with a thermistor?

Here is what I think to do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEyjh4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should work as temperature change to speed up or down the fan, right?

I do not want to make a IC controlled fan controler for it. I need to work in very tiny box beetween actually existing fan wires  (it makes too much noise) so the idea is to lower its speed by few % only.

I may be able to work around with a mosfet "classical" fan drive schematic but then I need to deport that elsewhere in the box.

I mean something like this:

[image]

Is first schematic useable or I need to work around second one  (with the mosfet?)

Comment: Where is the thermistor relative to the fan or whatever it is you are trying to cool?

Comment: Have you attempted a loop analysis?  This is a closed loop system with the feedback path being a thermal one through the fan's airflow to the thermistor (and whatever is causing the thermistor to heat up).

Comment: @SteveSh: it should be quite close (maybe 5mm)

Comment: I did not try any loop analysis yet, I 'm looking for poc for the moment (without calucation or any componant choosen :)

Comment: Without a proper loop analysis, it's difficult to say how that would work. My first inclination is that the loop would tend to limit cycle, with the fan speeding up and slowing down constantly.

Comment: You may want to find a switch that is less Vgs vs Id vs temp sensitive @ <200mA

Comment: I don't really buy the "can't have any IC in there" argument: All you'd need is a single microcontroller with a built-in temperature monitor (most not-really-least-end MCUs have such) and maybe an external mosfet. That'd amount to a maybe 8 × 14mm board, before it even gets tricky. how much smaller does it have to be?

Comment: @MarcusMüller   it's also to keep it very cheap ; whould be all of  very very cheap between 0 & 4 $ fullset   ;   feating in the box ; & very simple (in case of future other modifications)                  ;)

Comment: I did 10k for $2 with therm. bridge ,NPN , trimpot and LM317. tuned for 45~55'C 0 to max RPM

Comment: Insufficient conditions to oscillate like hysteresis.   Also Cap response is ~ 1ms  but T is not very accurate with Vt tolerances

Comment: Nice! My Alternative: [31 ct microcontroller](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Silicon-Labs/EFM8BB10F2I-A-QFN20?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs0L%252B%252BydDbPCgu7%252BU41lY9dDjTdfdVM5jl12UFD08YT7A%3D%3D) + [10ct voltage reg](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology-Micrel/MIC5504-33YM5-TR?qs=sGAEpiMZZMt1hubY80%2Fs8OgSipeHYxH5%252B3tm9wlHvtMZssu6ERCGLw%3D%3D) + 5ct decoupling capacitor + 5ct NPN transistor + 1ct base resistor + [1.79€ PCB](https://jlcpcb.com/quote#/?orderType=1&stencilWidth=8&stencilLength=14&stencilCounts=5&stencilLayer=2&stencilPly=1.6&) = 2.31€ for the whole PCB.

Comment: (single-quantity pricing) That would allow to program the thing for adjustable hysteresis, allow you to PWM the Fan instead of burning power in a linear-mode transistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so Idea is to lower its speed by few % only

The first circuit will work with the correct resistance values, but wastes power. A few % will make little difference to the cooling, so remove R2 (the thermistor?) and adjust the resistance of R1 to drop the fan speed by a few percent. So long as the resistance is low enough for the fan to start up it should be fine. You could also try it without the capacitor.

If you need temperature control then combine that with the second circuit by putting the resistor across the FET Drain-Source. This will make the fan run a bit faster when temperature exceeds a threshold. The FET won't dissipate much power so it can be quite small.